# How do I make SublimeText's SFTP plugin ignore "same age" files?

Tags: sublimetext2, sftp

I currently use Sublime Text 2 with the [Sublime SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) plugin, one of my biggest annoyances when using the plugin is the constant "same age" files confirmation dialog. For example, if I upload **file.php** to my server, and then restart Sublime Text, or try to sync to the server, it will often ask me "Download **file.php** (same age)?". Since it specifically says "same age", I know that the plugin is aware that the file was modified at the exact same time as my current copy, so it should not be questioning me whether to download it or not.

What I want is to be able to fix this behavior to ignore unmodified files; as far as I can see from the documentation, there is not a config option for this. I would like to know if anyone has managed to fix this problem, for example if they have found a config setting to repair this, or if it is not possible.

If it is not possible to get Sublime SFTP to ignore these files, could anyone perhaps suggest an alternative plugin with similar functionality, without this flaw? Note: I am on Windows, so please suggest plugins which work correctly on the Windows version of Sublime Text 2. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Insert:

```
"sync_same_age": false,
```

in your sftp_config.json file. (The file with the ftp-settings of the ftp you're working on).
Now, Sublime SFTP won't sync files with approximately the same age as the file on the server.

**Edit:**
Oops, this isn't solving your problem. This is for syncing, not for uploading. I don't know the answer :|

Comment: It really seems that this is unfixable without modification to the plugin. Until then I'm just using SFTP mounted as a directory in my Ubuntu VM.

Comment: I am trying to find a fix for that as well. Sent a mail with a feature improvement request to their support address. Will keep this updated.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue with:
  "sync_down_on_open": false,

, NOT WITH:
  "sync_same_age": false,